# Parsing input in C, the case for scanf

Tags: c

I have the following input:

```
2
2 5
4 6
1
1 1
```

where each first number encodes the number of cases to follow. This is pretty common in the ACM problems. I've tried successfully to do it using `fgets` and then `sscanf` (I always end up doing this anyway :(, but out of curiosity, is there a way to just use `scanf`? Where does the file pointer end up if I do something like

```
scanf("%d",&x)
for (f=0;f<x;f++) {
  scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
}
```

Would that work, is there a better way using just `scanf`?

Comment: Yes, that works if the input is well-formed.

Comment: @DanielFischer: This is usuall all within a `while(1)` loop or something of the sort, how do I test for EOF with the first `scanf`?

Comment: Meh, I think I got it...  this `while(scanf("%d", &cases)==1)` would work, I think... no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is well-formed - as you can expect for online judges - the pattern you have works.

For the example input and loop, the input up to and including the `'6'` would be consumed, leaving the newline after that to be skipped by the next `scanf` call.

> This is usuall all within a `while(1)` loop or something of the sort, how do I test for `EOF` with the first scanf?

If you don't have a count of testcases and need to detect the end of input yourself, use the return value of `scanf`,

```
while(scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
    for(f = 0; f < x; ++f) {
        scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
        /* do something clever */
    }
 }
```

When the conversion fails, you have reached the end of input, the input was malformed, or the input stream was corrupted. In none of these cases can you recover.